# Xcode Crashes with Assertion Failure in SourceCache

Tags: xcode, macos, ios5, xcode4.2

I am getting following error when I try to edit any file in my project.

```
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFoundation/IDEFoundation-943/Framework/Classes/Model/SourceControl/IDESourceControlTreeItem.m:771
Details:  (((IDESourceControlWorkingTree *)self.sourceTree).origin) should not be nil.
Object:   <IDESourceControlWorkingTreeItem: 0x401a17c00>
Method:   -repositoryURLString
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40010a260>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
0  0x00000001012fe366 -[IDEAssertionHandler  handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
1  0x00000001009751a4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
2  0x0000000100f4b455 -[IDESourceControlWorkingTreeItem repositoryURLString] (in IDEFoundation)
3  0x00007fff87b27434 _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter (in Foundation)
4  0x00007fff87b273e9 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] (in Foundation)
5  0x00007fff87b46e76 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] (in Foundation)
6  0x00007fff909a63f1 -[NSArrayController _multipleValueForKeyPath:atIndex:] (in AppKit)
7  0x00007fff909a54e5 -[NSArrayController _singleValueForKeyPath:] (in AppKit)
8  0x00007fff9070c09a -[_NSControllerObjectProxy valueForKeyPath:] (in AppKit)
9  0x00007fff87b46e39 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] (in Foundation)
10  0x00007fff87b46e39 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] (in Foundation)
11  0x00007fff9070bf46 -[NSBinder _valueForKeyPath:ofObject:mode:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:] (in AppKit)
12  0x00007fff9070bc30 -[NSBinder valueForBinding:resolveMarkersToPlaceholders:] (in AppKit)
13  0x00007fff9090fc92 -[NSValueBinder _referenceBindingValue] (in AppKit)
14  0x00007fff9090faa3 -[NSValueBinder _adjustObject:mode:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:editableState:adjustState:] (in AppKit)
15  0x00007fff9090f788 -[NSValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] (in AppKit)
16  0x00007fff909275af -[NSTextValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] (in AppKit)
17  0x00007fff906fdbdb -[NSObject(NSKeyValueBindingCreation) bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] (in AppKit)
18  0x0000000100b38c0d -[NSObject(DVTBindingUtilities) dvt_bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] (in DVTKit)
19  0x0000000101358251 -[IDEInspectorBasicStringProperty bindAndConfigure] (in IDEKit)
20  0x00000001013ff200 -[IDEInspectorPathFieldProperty bindAndConfigure] (in IDEKit)
21  0x000000010134e1c9 -[IDEInspectorProperty viewDidInstall] (in IDEKit)
22  0x00007fff8b3ee2e1 -[NSObject performSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
23  0x00007fff8b3f2722 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
24  0x0000000101407e8d -[IDEInspectorPropertyContainingView propertiesDidInstall] (in IDEKit)
25  0x0000000101407fcf -[IDEInspectorPropertyContainingView viewDidMoveToWindow] (in IDEKit)
26  0x00007fff907f9153 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
27  0x00007fff90725124 __NSViewRecursionHelper (in AppKit)
28  0x00007fff8b385314 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
29  0x00007fff907f90d7 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
30  0x00007fff90725124 __NSViewRecursionHelper (in AppKit)
31  0x00007fff8b385314 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
32  0x00007fff907f90d7 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
33  0x00007fff90725124 __NSViewRecursionHelper (in AppKit)
34  0x00007fff8b385314 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
35  0x00007fff907f90d7 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
36  0x00007fff90725124 __NSViewRecursionHelper (in AppKit)
37  0x00007fff8b385314 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
38  0x00007fff907f90d7 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
39  0x00007fff90725124 __NSViewRecursionHelper (in AppKit)
40  0x00007fff8b385314 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
41  0x00007fff907f90d7 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
42  0x00007fff907f73e2 -[NSView addSubview:] (in AppKit)
43  0x00000001046785b4 -[NSView(IBAppKitViewIntegration) ibSwizzledNSViewDebug_addSubview:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
44  0x0000000100bb167d -[DVTDisclosureView layoutTopDown] (in DVTKit)
45  0x0000000100b291c3 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
46  0x0000000100b29272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
47  0x0000000100b29272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
48  0x0000000100b29272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
49  0x0000000100b29272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
50  0x0000000100b29272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
51  0x0000000100b29272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
52  0x0000000100b29272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
53  0x0000000100b29272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
54  0x0000000100b29272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
55  0x0000000100b29272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
56  0x0000000100b29037 +[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:] (in DVTKit)
57  0x0000000100b28de1 -[DVTAutoLayoutView viewWillDraw] (in DVTKit)
58  0x00007fff90723c11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
59  0x00007fff90723c11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
60  0x00007fff90723c11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
61  0x00007fff90723c11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
62  0x00007fff90722952 -[NSView _sendViewWillDrawInRect:clipRootView:suppressRecursion:] (in AppKit)
63  0x00007fff907216c1 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] (in AppKit)
64  0x00007fff9072107d _handleWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraints (in AppKit)
65  0x00007fff8b3b6f37 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
66  0x00007fff8b3b6e96 __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation)
67  0x00007fff8b38c159 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
68  0x00007fff8b38bae6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
69  0x00007fff8f1dd3d3 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
70  0x00007fff8f1e463d ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
71  0x00007fff8f1e44ca BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode (in HIToolbox)
72  0x00007fff906e53f1 _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
73  0x00007fff906e4cf5 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
74  0x00007fff906e162d -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
75  0x00007fff9096080c NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
76  0x0000000100904eec (in Xcode)
```

I tried clearing XCode cache as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4) question, but that didn't work.
I tried reinstalling xcode but that also failed.

I am using Xcode Version 4.2.1 on MAC OSX Version 10.7.2 (Lion).

Let me know if you have any suggestions regarding the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solved now. This was due to missing repository in XCode. I had to go to Organizer -> Repositories and press +  button in bottom left corner to add repository. After which my project is compiling very well. Thanks Horst for your effort though.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem for me. XCode still keeps crashing, but only if i want to edit specific classes. And sometimes if i'm fast enough xcode also saves these small edits, like deleting a character or something like that. Do you have any other idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: ok, after manually deleting all repos from the organizer and then adding a new repo and a new working copy of the project I had to close xcode and then open the project file of the project i added the working copy. That solve the problem. Thx for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Read-only source/plist/project files had been the root cause for the same problem with my Xcode. You may just verify that all files in your project folder are writable.