# Xcode 4.3.2 crashing on source editing.

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, xcode4.2, xcode4.3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode Crashes with Assertion Failure in SourceCache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708231/xcode-crashes-with-assertion-failure-in-sourcecache)

I just installed XCode 4.3.2. It crashes every time I tried to edit source code. Sometimes at moment when I just opened source file (*.m), sometimes when I placed cursor in place, sometimes when I actually started typing. Anyway, I can't type any line of code.

At the same time, I can change build settings, perform build and run my apps without any problems.

XCode 4.2 woks well on the same machine.

```
Process:         Xcode [731]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.3.2 (1177)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-1177000000000000~6
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 7171108
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [132]

Date/Time:       2012-04-09 09:47:21.737 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.3 (11D50d)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          677289 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           63
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  5129 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   9
Anonymous UUID:                      242558D6-04D0-4CA7-875F-AEA455F19216

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4E2002
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFoundation/IDEFoundation-1192/Framework/Classes/Model/SourceControl/IDESourceControlTreeItem.m:775
Details:  (((IDESourceControlWorkingTree *)self.sourceTree).origin) should not be nil.
Object:   <IDESourceControlWorkingTreeItem: 0x404eab060>
Method:   -repositoryURLString
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40010a220>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000102ef7b9f -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x00000001023ad635 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000102a1c14f -[IDESourceControlWorkingTreeItem repositoryURLString] (in IDEFoundation)
  3  0x00007fff82baf384 _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter (in Foundation)
  4  0x00007fff82baf339 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] (in Foundation)
  5  0x00007fff82bcedc6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] (in Foundation)
  6  0x00007fff8b1c28c9 -[NSArrayController _multipleValueForKeyPath:atIndex:] (in AppKit)
  7  0x00007fff8b1c19bd -[NSArrayController _singleValueForKeyPath:] (in AppKit)
  8  0x00007fff8af28c36 -[_NSControllerObjectProxy valueForKeyPath:] (in AppKit)
  9  0x00007fff82bced89 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] (in Foundation)
 10  0x00007fff82bced89 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] (in Foundation)
 11  0x00007fff8af28ae2 -[NSBinder _valueForKeyPath:ofObject:mode:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:] (in AppKit)
 12  0x00007fff8af287cc -[NSBinder valueForBinding:resolveMarkersToPlaceholders:] (in AppKit)
 13  0x00007fff8b12c07e -[NSValueBinder _referenceBindingValue] (in AppKit)
 14  0x00007fff8b12be8f -[NSValueBinder _adjustObject:mode:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:editableState:adjustState:] (in AppKit)
 15  0x00007fff8b12bb74 -[NSValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] (in AppKit)
 16  0x00007fff8b1438cf -[NSTextValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] (in AppKit)
 17  0x00007fff8af1a777 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueBindingCreation) bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] (in AppKit)
 18  0x000000010263d8fa -[NSObject(DVTBindingUtilities) dvt_bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] (in DVTKit)
 19  0x0000000102e04762 -[IDEInspectorBasicStringProperty bindAndConfigure] (in IDEKit)
 20  0x0000000102e095c5 -[IDEInspectorPathFieldProperty bindAndConfigure] (in IDEKit)
 21  0x0000000102e0452d -[IDEInspectorProperty viewDidInstall] (in IDEKit)
 22  0x00007fff8374e021 -[NSObject performSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
 23  0x00007fff83752462 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
 24  0x0000000102e044f3 -[IDEInspectorPropertyContainingView propertiesDidInstall] (in IDEKit)
 25  0x0000000102e0449b -[IDEInspectorPropertyContainingView viewDidMoveToWindow] (in IDEKit)
 26  0x00007fff8b01577d -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
 27  0x00007fff8af41c08 __NSViewRecursionHelper (in AppKit)
 28  0x00007fff836e4ea4 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
 29  0x00007fff8b015766 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
 30  0x00007fff8af41c08 __NSViewRecursionHelper (in AppKit)
 31  0x00007fff836e4ea4 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
 32  0x00007fff8b015766 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
 33  0x00007fff8af41c08 __NSViewRecursionHelper (in AppKit)
 34  0x00007fff836e4ea4 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
 35  0x00007fff8b015766 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
 36  0x00007fff8af41c08 __NSViewRecursionHelper (in AppKit)
 37  0x00007fff836e4ea4 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
 38  0x00007fff8b015766 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
 39  0x00007fff8af41c08 __NSViewRecursionHelper (in AppKit)
 40  0x00007fff836e4ea4 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
 41  0x00007fff8b015766 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
 42  0x00007fff8b013999 -[NSView addSubview:] (in AppKit)
 43  0x000000010564d36c -[NSView(IBAppKitViewIntegration) ibSwizzledNSViewDebug_addSubview:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
 44  0x000000010266cd1c -[DVTDisclosureView layoutTopDown] (in DVTKit)
 45  0x0000000102633adf +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] (in DVTKit)
 46  0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] (in DVTKit)
 47  0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] (in DVTKit)
 48  0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] (in DVTKit)
 49  0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] (in DVTKit)
 50  0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] (in DVTKit)
 51  0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] (in DVTKit)
 52  0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] (in DVTKit)
 53  0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] (in DVTKit)
 54  0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] (in DVTKit)
 55  0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] (in DVTKit)
 56  0x000000010263393c +[DVTLayoutView_ML _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:] (in DVTKit)
 57  0x000000010264782b -[DVTLayoutView_ML viewWillDraw] (in DVTKit)
 58  0x00007fff8af406fc -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 59  0x00007fff8af406fc -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 60  0x00007fff8af406fc -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 61  0x00007fff8af406fc -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 62  0x00007fff8af3f441 -[NSView _sendViewWillDrawInRect:clipRootView:suppressRecursion:] (in AppKit)
 63  0x00007fff8af3e1ac -[NSView displayIfNeeded] (in AppKit)
 64  0x00007fff8af3db69 _handleWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraints (in AppKit)
 65  0x00007fff83716bd7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 66  0x00007fff83716b36 __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation)
 67  0x00007fff836ebce9 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 68  0x00007fff836eb676 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 69  0x00007fff8791331f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 70  0x00007fff8791a51b ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 71  0x00007fff8791a456 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode (in HIToolbox)
 72  0x00007fff8af01f5d _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 73  0x00007fff8af01861 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 74  0x00007fff8aefe19d -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 75  0x00007fff8b17cb88 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 76  0x0000000102326eec (in Xcode)

objc[731]: garbage collection is ON
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a43ce2 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6b7d2 pthread_kill + 95
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae5ca7a abort + 143
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102ef760e +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:] + 506
4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001023ad635 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 128
5   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000102a1c14f -[IDESourceControlWorkingTreeItem repositoryURLString] + 1512
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82baf384 _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter + 62
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82baf339 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 392
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82bcedc6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 348
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b1c28c9 -[NSArrayController _multipleValueForKeyPath:atIndex:] + 84
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b1c19bd -[NSArrayController _singleValueForKeyPath:] + 151
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af28c36 -[_NSControllerObjectProxy valueForKeyPath:] + 77
12  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82bced89 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 287
13  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82bced89 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 287
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af28ae2 -[NSBinder _valueForKeyPath:ofObject:mode:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:] + 654
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af287cc -[NSBinder valueForBinding:resolveMarkersToPlaceholders:] + 171
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b12c07e -[NSValueBinder _referenceBindingValue] + 31
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b12be8f -[NSValueBinder _adjustObject:mode:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:editableState:adjustState:] + 647
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b12bb74 -[NSValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 303
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b1438cf -[NSTextValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 43
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af1a777 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueBindingCreation) bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] + 591
21  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010263d8fa -[NSObject(DVTBindingUtilities) dvt_bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] + 44
22  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102e04762 -[IDEInspectorBasicStringProperty bindAndConfigure] + 527
23  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102e095c5 -[IDEInspectorPathFieldProperty bindAndConfigure] + 51
24  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102e0452d -[IDEInspectorProperty viewDidInstall] + 25
25  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8374e021 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 49
26  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff83752462 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 786
27  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102e044f3 -[IDEInspectorPropertyContainingView propertiesDidInstall] + 50
28  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102e0449b -[IDEInspectorPropertyContainingView viewDidMoveToWindow] + 62
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b01577d -[NSView _setWindow:] + 2618
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af41c08 __NSViewRecursionHelper + 25
31  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836e4ea4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b015766 -[NSView _setWindow:] + 2595
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af41c08 __NSViewRecursionHelper + 25
34  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836e4ea4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b015766 -[NSView _setWindow:] + 2595
36  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af41c08 __NSViewRecursionHelper + 25
37  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836e4ea4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
38  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b015766 -[NSView _setWindow:] + 2595
39  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af41c08 __NSViewRecursionHelper + 25
40  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836e4ea4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
41  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b015766 -[NSView _setWindow:] + 2595
42  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af41c08 __NSViewRecursionHelper + 25
43  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836e4ea4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
44  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b015766 -[NSView _setWindow:] + 2595
45  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b013999 -[NSView addSubview:] + 405
46  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration    0x000000010564d36c -[NSView(IBAppKitViewIntegration) ibSwizzledNSViewDebug_addSubview:] + 49
47  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010266cd1c -[DVTDisclosureView layoutTopDown] + 131
48  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000102633adf +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] + 206
49  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] + 418
50  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] + 418
51  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] + 418
52  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] + 418
53  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] + 418
54  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] + 418
55  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] + 418
56  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] + 418
57  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] + 418
58  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000102633bb3 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:] + 418
59  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010263393c +[DVTLayoutView_ML _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:] + 108
60  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010264782b -[DVTLayoutView_ML viewWillDraw] + 161
61  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af406fc -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
62  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af406fc -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
63  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af406fc -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
64  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af406fc -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
65  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af3f441 -[NSView _sendViewWillDrawInRect:clipRootView:suppressRecursion:] + 1358
66  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af3e1ac -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1039
67  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af3db69 _handleWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraints + 648
68  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff83716bd7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
69  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff83716b36 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 374
70  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836ebce9 __CFRunLoopRun + 825
71  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836eb676 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
72  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8791331f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
73  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8791a51b ReceiveNextEventCommon + 181
74  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8791a456 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
75  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af01f5d _DPSNextEvent + 659
76  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af01861 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
77  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8aefe19d -[NSApplication run] + 470
78  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b17cb88 NSApplicationMain + 867
79  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x0000000102326eec 0x102326000 + 3820

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a447e6 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff836005be _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 923
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff835ff14e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a4267a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a41d71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836e36fc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836ebe64 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836eb676 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82beeffb +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 335
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82be374e -[NSThread main] + 68
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82be36c6 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae698bf _pthread_start + 335
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6cb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a4267a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a41d71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836e36fc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836ebe64 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836eb676 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.DTDeviceKit           0x0000000108be8ee8 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 298
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82be374e -[NSThread main] + 68
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82be36c6 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae698bf _pthread_start + 335
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6cb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a43df2 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff83734cdb __CFSocketManager + 1355
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae698bf _pthread_start + 335
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6cb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a4267a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a41d71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836e36fc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836ebe64 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836eb676 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82b94f9f -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 267
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82b94e8b -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 62
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82be374e -[NSThread main] + 68
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82be36c6 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae698bf _pthread_start + 335
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6cb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a43bca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6d274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8a7a7b3c CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 710
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8a7a785d _ZL13startIOThreadPv + 148
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae698bf _pthread_start + 335
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6cb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a44192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6b594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6cb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a43bca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6d274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000105e23b48 -[XCInvocationQueue _processInvocationsInThreadSlotNumber:] + 348
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82be374e -[NSThread main] + 68
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82be36c6 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae698bf _pthread_start + 335
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6cb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a44192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6b594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6cb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a43bca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6d274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82be54e4 -[NSCondition wait] + 261
3   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiPhoneSupport   0x0000000108a9d45f 0x108a69000 + 214111
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82be374e -[NSThread main] + 68
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82be36c6 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae698bf _pthread_start + 335
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6cb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a44192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6b594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6cb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a44192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6b594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6cb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a44192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6b594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6cb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a44192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6b594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6cb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a44192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6b594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6cb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a44192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6b594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6cb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a4267a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a41d71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836e36fc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836ebe64 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836eb676 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff835c92f2 _ZL20SpotlightQueryThreadPv + 434
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae698bf _pthread_start + 335
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6cb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81a43e42 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae1fdea nanosleep + 164
2   com.apple.CoreSymbolication     0x00007fff885523bb cleaner_thread_main(void*) + 42
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae698bf _pthread_start + 335
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ae6cb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x00007fff61f219d8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000507  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff61f21a00  rsp: 0x00007fff61f219d8
   r8: 0x00007fff71feefb8   r9: 0x0000000000000063  r10: 0x00007fff81a43d0a  r11: 0xffffff80002d8220
  r12: 0x00007fff82dba281  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x00007fff71ff1960  r15: 0x00007fff61f21b08
  rip: 0x00007fff81a43ce2  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x0000000103a9f140
Logical CPU: 0
```

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708231/xcode-crashes-with-assertion-failure-in-sourcecache